# masonry is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I am messing around with [jquery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html) and the simplest of it honestly will not work. I feel like I am just missing something stupid, but this is my code:

```
$container = $('#contain');
$container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.box'
});
```

## [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chqHf/)

why wont masonry work?

Answer (score 1):

You're not including the correct file. Get a packaged Masonry build from [the website](http://masonry.desandro.com/#getting-started) and it should work.